# Git pull on dev after remote git reset --hard origin/master doesn't show changes

Tags: git

So my coworker made git reset --hard origin/master on dev branch, he pushed forced that to remote. Thing is I have locally dev branch from before that and when I make git pull I don't get proper state, I do get some updates but on my dev branch there are still things from before that git reset. Git pull is up to date but git status is "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 152 commits". I know I can use reset hard to remote dev, wondering why is this so and is the proper way to update local branch when remote was reset always to also reset your local branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Git pull is up to date but git status is "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 152 commits". I know I can use reset hard to remote dev, wondering why is this so

When you do

```
git checkout dev
git pull
```

and get `branch is up to date`, this means that your local `dev` branch already contains everything on your remote's `dev` branch.

> wondering why is this so and is the proper way to update local branch when remote was reset always to also reset your local branch?

When you do

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard origin/dev
```

you will lose all of the work on your `dev` branch. There is no general answer if this is always the correct course of action. You need to discuss with your team whether it is appropriate to throw all of those commits away. If there is another branch that contains those commits, then there is less risk here. You can merge that other branch in when it is appropriate. If there is no other way to access those commits, then you need to decide as a team if they are needed or not.

Comment: I was being a bit stupid, ofcourse if I have local branch that is ahead of master, git pull won't set local branch to that state unless head is reset to that position. Realised that myself a bit after asking question, thnx on confirming this info.